# Updating message in task hangs the application

Tags: java, javafx, java.util.concurrent

I am using a background `Thread` to run my loading code and wish to bind the `MessageProperty` of the `Task` to a label.

However, when calling `updateMessage()` the task hangs; the message is never updated and the next line of code does not execute.

This is using JDK 1.10.1.  Here is an MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        Label label = new Label("Message");
        root.getChildren().add(label);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        Task loadingTask = new LoadingTask();
        Thread loadingThread = new Thread(loadingTask);
        loadingThread.setDaemon(true);

        label.textProperty().bind(loadingTask.messageProperty());
        loadingThread.start();

        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class LoadingTask<Void> extends Task {
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading task ...");
        updateMessage("Loading task ...");
        System.out.println("Message: " + getMessage());

        return null;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Loading task ...
```

The second `System.out.println()` is never executed.

**Edit:**

I added a simple GUI to my MCVE with a label bound to the `MessageProperty`. The label **does** get updated to show "Loading task ..." but the console output remains the same; code after the `updateMessage()` method is called does not execute.

**2nd Edit:**

I ran my step debugger, and an `IllegalStateException` is being thrown from the `Task` class: "Task must only be used from the FX Application Thread"

I'm not sure what that means as the whole point is to run this task on a different thread...

Comment: My actual application DOES show a GUI, however, @fabian. I just left it out of the MCVE. I've updated my question with a simple GUI.

Comment: Every thread that actually updates GUI **must** run in FX Application Thread. However, I couldn't get any output in the console even when I started your code in the "ordinary" class (without any GUI), although `System.out.println(loadingThread.isAlive());` after `loadingThread.start();` outputs `true`...

Comment: @zlakad - My application (and MCVE) do not attempt to update the GUI on any other thread. The error message seems to say that tasks can only be executed on the JFX thread, which is not right.

Comment: Check your imports. There should be `import javafx.concurrent.Task;`

Comment: Yes, it's already there...

Comment: It seems that the `call()` method is the background method NOT in FX thread... According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html): *Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it ensures that every change to its public properties, as well as change notifications for state, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on the main JavaFX application thread. Accessing these properties from a background thread (including the call() method) will result in runtime exceptions being raised.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only issue is, that you must not access `getMessage()` from another thread than the FX UI-Thread. Try `Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println("Message: " + getMessage()));`